# To rule out or disable some files within a directory

Tags: filesystems

How can Linux rule out or disable some files within a directory in order that those will not be included, ie. will completely be ignored/skipped, when in the progress of the directory compression process (squash, tar etc) as it compressing

We know that moving those up temporary to be moved them back again will work but clearly edgier than if there's such way just toggling on off as said

Comment: I think in removing `read` permissions to every file (but you will have to revert to `read` perms). Using that. some commands such as `tar`, `gzip`, etc won't be able to tar/zip those files. However by using `sudo` or being logged as  `root` you will be able to tar/zip the files.